# How do we know that an SSL signature belongs to a specific certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, x509

I am reading the following article about HTTPS:

http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html

I do understand how we can verify that a signature was truly created by VeriSign.

But how can we know that VeriSign created this signature for this specific domain that we are connected to (or actually for this certificate)?

Since I can see the certificate, including the signature, what stops me from creating my own certificate, replacing the signature with the one I saw on the Amazon.com certificate, and pretending to have a certificate signed by VeriSign?

Answer (score 1):

> Since I can see the certificate, including the signature, what stops me from creating my own certificate, replacing the signature with the one I saw on the Amazon.com certificate, and pretending to have a certificate signed by VeriSign?

A certificate has a subject, public key, issuer and signature (among other fields). For example, a subject might be `example.com` (a DNS name) or `joe@example.com` (and email address), and the issuer might be `Startcom`. The issuer's signature binds the subject's public key to the subject. That's all a certificate does: it binds a public key to an entity through an authority's signature. The authority is often called "trusted" or "trusted third party".

So the person who is validating the certificate you are trying to forge will extract the issuer, get the issuer's public key (that's in a different certificate), and then use the issuer's public key to verify your certificate data. Since you forged the signature (i.e., used a different public key than that of the issuer), the signature verification will fail.

Comment: On the certificate I'm starting from, the issuer is VeriSign, the subject is amazon.com. Am I correct? All I do is more or less replacing amazon.com with mydomain.com, and sending this forged cert to browsers that access my website at mydomain.com. What I'm trying to tell to these browsers is, "look guys, I have a certificate from VeriSign that guarantees that I am a legitimate website. And yes, my issuer is a trusted CA, check him out!"

Comment: It should not work. As soon as you swap `amazon.com` with `example.com`, the certificate data will change. The signature calculated during verification will be different than the signature calculated by the CA and present in the certificate before modification. But I would encourage you to try it. You never know what broken implementation you will encounter  or what a user will click through. Your best chance of success will likely be a user clicking through a warning.

Comment: Honestly just trying to understand why we are all protected.. that's all. So when the article explains why the manipulated signature conforms to the PKCS #1 v1.5 standard http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2313#page-9 which is why "the decrypted value is properly formatted", my thought is: yes, this shows that the signature was created by someone who had the VeriSign secret key (or someone trusted by VeriSign..), but what in the signature associates it with amazon.com or the certificate itself? The article uses a little sloppy language "we get this "decrypted" signature hex value"...

Comment: (continued) ...actually not decrypted since we don't have the secret key to do this. It's more like "mathematically manipulated to show a proper format". What would convince me that the signature was created by VeriSign especially for amazon.com? Maybe if for example after the manipulation I would see in the resulted string something like "amazon.com". But I don't. Which brings me back to the first question.

Comment: It's still amazing to me how so many people use this algorithm to protect their privacy, without truly understanding it, at least conceptually if not the fine mathematical details.

Comment: @rapt Let's say you replace something on a cert and use your own private key to create the signature for your forged cert. When my browser gets your forged cert, it uses the public key of the issuing CA to validate your forged signature. But the public key does not correspond to the private key which you used so the cert hashes don't match. And that's how I know your forged cert is invalid. Where do I get the public key from, you ask? It comes with the browser pre-installed.

Comment: @gilden But I do not try to create a new signature. I use (almost) exactly the same certificate amazon sent me when I tried to https-contact its website (so same signature and same public key as on amazon's cert). The only thing I change on that cert is the name field (i.e. the name of the website/computer who was given the authority by the signer to use this cert to authenticate itself). So I'm going to change this field from "amazon.com" to "rapt.com". Now I can use this cert to convince people rapt.com is a trusted website. What in the SSL algorithm is going to make me fail in my scheme?

Answer (score 0):

Because the public key with which you can verify the signature is part of the certificate and also part of the signature. So you can't change any of those things without breaking the signature.

Comment: Then I would replace not only the signature to the one on Amazon certificate, I would replace also the public key to the one on Amazon certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> @gilden But I do not try to create a new signature. I use (almost) exactly the same certificate amazon sent me when I tried to https-contact its website (so same signature and same public key as on amazon's cert). The only thing I change on that cert is the name field (i.e. the name of the website/computer who was given the authority by the signer to use this cert to authenticate itself). So I'm going to change this field from "amazon.com" to "rapt.com". Now I can use this cert to convince people rapt.com is a trusted website. What in the SSL algorithm is going to make me fail in my scheme?

Then the browser/client will use the amazon.com public key to communicate with your server, for which you do not have the corresponding private key. Hence you will not be able to decrypt the pre_master_secret from the client certificate message, and the ssl/tls handshake will fail.